# When viewed in older browser,the text appears right next to the other text in wrapper div when its supposed to be on the right side

Tags: html, css

In my website,http://rajitaviation.000webhostapp.com there is a wrapper div in which there is text on left  then image and then text on right. But when viewed on older browsers like firefox 35, the text renders right next to the text on left and overlaps the image help!

If I apply resets then my font size becomes defaults which I don't want so is 
any way i can pull out a perfect website??

```css
.intro{
  width:100%;
  font-family:Anaheim;
  font-size:4.5vw;
  text-align:center;
}
.next{
     font-size:2.5vw;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.hero-image {
   background-image: url('G:/Aviaition/a350.jpg');
      background-position:center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:50% 100%;
   position: relative;
   width:100%;
}
.hero-image2{
   background-image: url('G:/Aviaition/a380.jpg');
   background-position:center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:50% 100%;
   position: relative;
   width:100%;
}
.hero-image3{
   background-image: url('G:/Aviaition/a321.jpg');
   background-position:center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:50% 100%;
   position: relative;
   width:100% ;
}
.hero-image4{
   background-image: url('G:/Aviaition/a340.jpg');
   background-position:center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:50% 100%;
   position: relative;
   width:100%;
}
.hero-image5{
   background-image: url('G:/Aviaition/a320.jpg');
   background-position:center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:50% 125%;
   position: relative;
   width:100%;
}
.hero-image6{
   background-image: url('G:/Aviaition/a319.jpg');
   background-position:center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:50% 100%;
   position: relative;
   width:100%;
}
.hero-image7{
   background-image: url('G:/Aviaition/a330.jpg');
   background-position:center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:50% 100%;
   position: relative;
   width:100%;
}
.hero-image8{
   background-image: url('G:/Aviaition/a318.jpg');
   background-position:center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:50% 100%;
   position: relative;
      width:100%;
}
.hero-image9{
   background-image: url('G:/Aviaition/a300.jpg');
   background-position:center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size:50% 100%;
   position: relative;
   width:100%;
}
.hero-text {
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   color: white;
   font-size:1.5vw;
}

.hero-text button {
   border: none;
   outline: 0;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 8px 7px;
   color: black;
   background-color: white;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size:1vw;
   width:100%;
}

.hero-text button:hover {
   background-color: white;
   color:black;
}
.text{
   text-align:left;
   font-family:Anaheim;
   font-size:2vw;
   float:left;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.text1{
     font-family:Anaheim;
     font-size:2.5vw;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
}
.text3{
     text-align:left;
     font-family:Anaheim;
     font-size:1.95vw;
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.text2{
     text-align:right;
     font-family:Anaheim;
     font-size:2.75vw;
     text-align: justify;
     text-align-last:right;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.text4{
     text-align:right;
     font-family:Anaheim;
     font-size:2.5vw;
     text-align: justify;
  text-justify:inherit;
     text-align-last:right;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.text6{
     text-align:right;
     font-family:Anaheim;
     font-size:2.75vw;
     text-align: justify;
     text-align-last:right;
   overflow:hidden;  
}  
.text7{
     text-align:right;
     font-family:Anaheim;
     font-size:2.5vw;
     text-align: justify;
     text-align-last:right;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
<span class="hide">
<div class="intro">
     Welcome To RAJIT GAMING-AVIATION!
<br>
<div class="next">
     Here you will find information about all airbus planes!
<br>
     Hope you enjoy!
</div>
</div>
<marquee direction=left; behavior=scroll; scrollamount=6; style="font-family:Anaheim;">
     This website is still under development.
     Information about planes and THE NEOs will 
  be out soon!
</marquee>
<hr>
<div class="hero-image">
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="text1">
     "The most advanced <br>airliner in the skies"<br>
     -Business insider
</div>
<div class="text7">
     Three models<br>A350-1000<br>A350-900<br>A350-800
</div>
</div>
<div class="hero-text">
<h1>THE A350</h1>
<button onclick="location.href='A350.html';">CHECK IT OUT!</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<hr>
<div class="hero-image2">
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="text1">
     "The biggest <br>airliner in the skies"<br>
     -Wikipedia
</div>
<div class="text6">
     Two models<br>A380-800<br>A380-f
</div>
</div>
<div class="hero-text">
<h1>THE A380</h1>
<button onclick="location.href='A380.html';">CHECK IT OUT!</button>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="hero-image3">
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="text3">
     "The most efficient <br>single-aisle<br>airliner ever built"<br>
     -Phillippine airlines
</div>
<div class="text2">
     Two models<br>A321-100<br>A321-200
</div>
</div>
<div class="hero-text">
<h1>THE A321</h1>
<button onclick="location.href='A321.html';">CHECK IT OUT!</button>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="hero-image4">
<div class="text">
     "The longest<br>airliner ever built"<br>
     -Trip advisor
</div>
<div class="text2">
     Four models<br>A340-200<br>500,600 and 300
</div>
<div class="hero-text">
<h1>THE A340</h1>
<button onclick="location.href='A340.html';">CHECK IT OUT!</button>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="hero-image5">
<div class="text">
  "The most<br>selling commercial<br>aircraft"<br>
  -wikipedia
</div>
<div class="text2">
  Two models<br>A320-100<br>A320-200
</div>
<div class="hero-text">
<h1>THE A320</h1>
<button onclick="location.href='A320.html';">CHECK IT OUT!</button>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="hero-image6">
<div class="text">
  "The beginning<br>of a new era of<br>efficiency of fuel"<br>
  -Lufthansa
</div>
<div class="text4">
     Eight models<br>A319-111,<br>112,113,114,115,<br>131,132 and 133
</div>
<div class="hero-text">
<h1>THE A319</h1>
<button onclick="location.href='A319.html';">CHECK IT OUT!</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="hero-image7">
<div class="text">
  "The A320<br>reimagined"<br>
  -Air India
</div>
<div class="text2">
  Three models<br>A330-200<br>A330-200F<br>A330-300
</div>
<div class="hero-text">
<h1>THE A330</h1>
<button onclick="location.href='A330.html';">CHECK IT OUT!</button>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="hero-image8">
<div class="text3">
  "The smallest and<br>most compact<br>commercial airliner yet"<br>
  -Air India
</div>
<div class="text4">
  Four models<br>A318-111,112,<br>121 and 122
</div>
<div class="hero-text">
<h1>THE A318</h1>
<button onclick="location.href='A318.html';">CHECK IT OUT!</button>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="hero-image9">
<div class="text3">
  "The world's first<br>twin-engine widebody<br> aircraft"<br>
  -Wikipedia
</div>
<div class="text2">
  Three models<br>A300B4<br>A300-600<br>A300B10
</div>
<div class="hero-text">
<h1>THE A300</h1>
<button onclick="location.href='A300.html';">CHECK IT OUT!</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try clear: both?

Comment: Please repost code as a minimal example. Thanks.

Comment: how to use clear: both??

Comment: As a side note i wonder when the `marquee` element won't work... although it deprecated long time ago it seems all browsers keep support it...